# Multiple Roots of Spheroidal Function

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I am trying to compute multiple roots of a spheroidal Function (`SpheroidalS1`). At first, I define function `RootsInRange` which evaluates roots within a given interval and then try to find `SpheroidalS1`'s roots using `RootsInRange`. Finally, I use those roots to define another variable `AnalyticalFrequencies`. Here's my code:

```
RootsInRange[δ_, {λ_, λmin_, λmax_}, opts___] := 
Module[{p, pts, x, f = Function[λ, Evaluate[δ]]}, 
p = Plot[f[λ], {λ, λmin, λmax}];
pts = Cases[First[p], Line[{x__}] -> x, Infinity]; 
pts = Map[First, 
Select[Split[pts, Sign[Last[#2]] == -Sign[Last[#1]] &], 
Length[#1] == 2 &], {2}]; (FindRoot[
f[λ] == 0, {λ, ##1}] &) /@ pts]

(*Define ellipsoid and then compute its spheroidal function's roots*)
t = 1.25; d = t^(-1/3) Sqrt[t^2 - 1]; ξ0 = t/Sqrt[t^2 - 1];
KD = Table[{N[
kd /. RootsInRange[
Re[SpheroidalS1[1, n, kd, ξ0]], {kd, 0, 60}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 5], 60]}, {n, 1, 10}];

(*Analytical Frequencies*)
AnalyticalFrequencies = 3*(10^8)*KD/(2*Pi*d) // N  // MatrixForm
```

However, while this is a working code, it tends to be very slow. How can we make root finding faster? Is there any other algorithm? Something else that we can do?

Comment: Missing a semicolon in the middle of the third line from the bottom?

Comment: You are right but that doesn't seem to solve my problem yet

Comment: You haven't defined `FilterOptions`

Comment: I 'am sorry but I didn't understand what you  mean. Could you be more specidfic please?

Comment: What is `FilterOptions` supposed to be? As far as I can see it's not a built in function.

Comment: if you fixed a typographic error please update the question.

Comment: Done! Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Fayre, it's from here [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Utilities/FilterOptions.html). Hope that helps you

Comment: `FilterOptions` appears to be an obsolete function.

Comment: So, should I replace it somehow?

Comment: I believe the `k` in `{k,0,20}` should be `kd` (the unknown in `SpheroidalS1` )

Comment: Unfortunately no ,doesn't change much

Comment: I didn't mean to say that's the only problem. Another issue is that your function returns complex results (with ~0 imaginary part).  Try `Re[SpheroidalS1[0, 0, kd, \[Xi]0]]`

Comment: Make the two `k`'s in the last expression `kd`, add `Re` and get rid of the `Evaluate[FilterOptions[Plot, opts]]]` and `Compiled` options all together and it works (takes a few minutes) . There are three roots approx `4.7,10.,15.4`.

Comment: george2079 thank you so much! It works like a charm!